# Using offset for custom post query

Tags: wordpress

Situation:

News page - Currently shows the latest 5 news items Archive page - Starts on post 6, I've setup pagination.

For testing purposes I've got 20 posts numbered 1 - 20.

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
     'category' => 7,
      'posts_per_page' => 5, 
      'offset' => ( $paged - 1 ) * $posts_per_page + 5,
     'paged' => $paged );
 ?>

<?php 

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts($args); 
?>
```

The above code works fine for archive page 1 but when I click page 2 in the pagination it skips 5 and jumps to post 16.

How would I resolve the above query to prevent skipping 5 posts?

Cheers, Dan

Comment: Where is `$paged` calculated in the code?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that bit. - It's above now

Comment: You need to calculate `$paged` before defining  `$args`, so just move the line you pasted now and put it above `$args`, that should help.

Comment: Now I'm only getting 1 article

Comment: Have you defined `$posts_per_page`? Also your calculation for offset needs to change, try `'offset' => ( $paged - 1 ) * 5`

Comment: Sweet, I've got it working by adding in your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So the final code should look like:

```
<?php 

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts($args); 

    $posts_per_page = 5;

    $args = array(
     'category' => 7,
      'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 
      'offset' => ( $paged - 1 ) * $posts_per_page ,
     'paged' => $paged );

 ?>
```